# How to make defined OCI tags in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, tags, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I don't know why I can't make tags like this. I don't have any issues on AWS.

```
resource "oci_core_public_ip" "public-ip-address-1" {
  compartment_id    = oci_identity_compartment.tf-compartment.id
  display_name      = "reserved public ip"
  lifetime          = "RESERVED"
  private_ip_id     = data.oci_core_private_ips.attach-public-ip-address-1.private_ips[0]["id"]
  defined_tags = {
    Lifecycle = "persistent"
  }
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}
```

I get this error:

```
╷
│ Error: invalid key structure found Lifecycle
│
│   with oci_core_public_ip.public-ip-address-1,
│   on compute.tf line 32, in resource "oci_core_public_ip" "public-ip-address-1":
│   32: resource "oci_core_public_ip" "public-ip-address-1" {
│
```

Do I have to declare tags elsewhere?

Comment: In the terraform docs for this resource the example puts double quotes around both the key and the value `defined_tags = {"Operations.CostCenter"= "42"}` have you tried putting your tag key `Lifecycle` in double quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you need to create a tag_namespace of Lifecycle

I wrote a example for you -

```
resource "oci_identity_tag_namespace" "generic" {
  # Required
  compartment_id = "CompartmentOCID"
  description    = "Generic namespace for adding generic labels"
  name           = "generic"
}

resource "oci_identity_tag" "generic_label_project" {
    # Required
    description = "Label tag used for adding a generic label"
    name = "label"
    tag_namespace_id = oci_identity_tag_namespace.generic.id

    # Optional
    is_cost_tracking = false
    is_retired = false
}

resource "oci_core_vcn" "service_vcn" {
  cidr_block     =     local.cidr_block
  compartment_id =     "CompartmentOCID"
  display_name =       "ServiceVCN"

  defined_tags = {
    "generic.label" = "persistent"
  }
}
```